# (VB.net) Web Scraping Issue

Tags: vb.net, text, web-scraping, nodes

I simply need to display this in a Richtext box instead of a MsgBox, But when I do I only get one line of text (in this case only the first sentence)

```
For each node in nodes 
    richtextbox3.text = node.innertext
next
```

^^^^ This doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Scrape()
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.metrolyrics.com/closer-lyrics-the-chainsmokers.html")
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
    Using res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        doc.Load(res.GetResponseStream())
    End Using

    Dim nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='verse']")
    If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            MsgBox(node.InnerText)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have to;

```
For each node in nodes 
    richtextbox3.text += node.innertext
next
```

Because you are replacing the new line each time.

And I really think this is a bad question, you didn't do any research nor 'undressing' the problem (go to the core of the problem and leave other code around it). Nobody else is going to benefit from this question, and the title doesn't match the problem

Comment: Thank you so much man!, that did it. Yes i know but i just needed a quick answer.... you have no idea what i have been through to get a working code for this.